# How to remove menu installed in wp-admin by a theme?

Tags: menus, themes, wp-admin, admin-menu

I installed [Placester](https://wordpress.org/plugins/placester/) theme.And then disabled it, and deleted it. But there is still a menu there. How can I remove it?
The only installed plugins are:

- Akismet
- Contact Form 7
- Google Analytics by Yoast
- Google Analytics Dashboard for WP
- Google Sitemap by BestWebSoft
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Hello Dolly
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Multipart robots.txt editor
- Really Simple CAPTCHA
- Wordfence Security
- WP Super Cache
- WP-PageNavi
- Yoast SEO

[image]

Comment: there must be some plugin activated with theme which is providing this menu just check it out and see if it works..

Comment: I have updated the post with installed plugins. There is nothing that shows anything related to Placester.

Comment: @Himanshu, thanks to you i got on the right track.

Comment: Happy To Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Placester was proved to be a simple not worthy theme. They left behind trash that left this menu in the admin panel.

The Placester plugin wouldn't show in the admin panel under the Plugins section. I used Putty to ssh to my server, then I had to go to the wordpress root folder, and delete all the files and subfolders by:

`'rm' -R /var/www/../root-folder/wp-content/plugins/placester/*`

That cleared the issue.